# Hyperlink is not opening on my JavaScript menu

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, href

in this menu i can put the class 'active' on the clicked and remove it from the others element, set the href but the href is not oppening. Where is the problem ?

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
const arr = ['Home', 'About', 'Contact', 'Projects'];

li.forEach((elementul, index) => {
    elementul.setAttribute('href', arr[index].toLocaleLowerCase() + '.html');

    elementul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        li.forEach(liElement => {
            liElement.classList.remove('active');
        });

        elementul.classList.add('active');

        console.log(elementul.href);
    });
});
```

```
html :
<li class='pagini' > 
 <a class='list-item'href='#' >${element} </a>            
</li>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` will stop the default behaviour ("openiog the link") from being executed.

Comment: if i not use ```preventDefault()``` it will not add the new class

Comment: Yes, because it will forward you to the page the link is linking too, which means the previous pages javascript is no longer able to do anything on the page that is now not loaded. Perhaps you wanna look into something like `liElement.classList.toggle('active', location.href.includes( arr[index].toLocaleLowerCase() + '.html' ));` to mark the active one on page load instead of after the click, because the click will send you away. Or you hardcode the `active` class in the relevant html pages.

Comment: Is the link supposed to point to an anchor within the same page, or is it linking to a different page? If the latter, then you can't do both at the same time - mark the link as "active", _and_ follow it. You'd need to mark it active in the _new_ page that loads, after the link was clicked.

Comment: CBroe, there are two different pages, home.html and about.html. I take tfrom the Array the name and o put it as href here  elementul.setAttribute('href', arr[index].toLocaleLowerCase() + '.html');

Answer (score 0):

By calling `event.preventDefault()` inside the `click` event listener, you are preventing the link from taking you where it would otherwise lead. Because when a new page is loaded your old script disappears, the approach you are taking should be to mark the `active` element on page load instead. Luckily enough, you can easily do that with your existing code:

```js
const menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll( '.list-item' );
const arr = [ 'Home', 'About', 'Contact', 'Projects' ];

menuLinks.forEach((a, index) => {
    
  const name = arr[index];
  const url = name.toLocaleLowerCase() + '.html';
  // Add the active class only if the 'path' (the part after the .com (TLD) in the domain) ends with the url to your page
  const isActive = location.pathname.endsWith( url );
  
  a.textContent = name;
  a.setAttribute( 'href', url );
  a.classList.toggle( 'active', isActive );
  
});
```

```html
<li class="pagini"> 
  <a class="list-item" href="#">First Link</a>            
</li>
```

I did make a few tweaks that I feel might put you on the right path to naming things: when selecting all your `<a>` it might be best to not name the array `li`, since its multiple `<a>` elements. And when looping over them you should probably use `a` or `anchor` instead `elementul`, as `ul` feels to refer to an `<ul>`, which isn't the element you are getting in your loop. This is not the point, but is worth having a think about to make your code easier to parse.

In conclusion, keep in mind that following a link loads in fresh, new HTML and JS, so your old script and whatever it knew will be discarded (and even just stopped entirely as soon as you follow a link, your script isn't persistent across pages).

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I initially monitored the clicks on the links, and constancy remained with this name. I will pay more attention to such events from now on. To persist across all pages, I suppose an "if" statement will need to be added, which I have prepared. Another method is currently unknown to me; I'm still at the beginning, with much more to learn. Once again, many thanks for your help. For the past two days, I haven't been able to find the issue.

Comment: No, your script is just not 'persistent' across page loads and never will be - your script will _always_ run from scratch when loading a page. It will just start all over again with the new page. If you want a script to be persistent, you need to use it to load and adjust content in the page itself without ever moving to another page. But otherwise, good luck! Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

How have you got the array of elements, I would but a class on each li element then do `var li = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassNameOfli")`

if that doesn't work try putting the the code in a async function

li.forEach((elementul, index) => {
elementul.setAttribute('href', arr[index].toLocaleLowerCase() + '.html');

```
elementul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addActive(elementul);
    });
});


async function addActive(elementul)
{    
    var li = document.getElementsByClassName("ClassNameOfli")
    await li.forEach(liElement => {
        liElement.classList.remove('active');
    });

    elementul.classList.add('active');

    console.log(elementul.href);
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the issue nor the solution. The issue is the `preventDefault`. So many questions. How is `await forEach` even a thing? That method isn't async, so you can't `await` it (you could, but it doesn't do anything). Neither are `classList` or its methods, none of those are `async`. Selecting the classes isn't the issue either, as the OP is asking why the links aren't working anymore? There is just no point to setting the href and then preventing the default...